# Removing NSString form NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an array with 3 strings that all equal "Farm"

When I try to remove ONLY ONE "Farm" with this line of code:

```
[array removeObject:@"Farm"];
```

It removes all.

How can I only remove one?

Comment: Find one and remove it by number rather than value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removeObject means **removes all occurrences in the array of a given object**.

See the description :

> This method uses indexOfObject: to locate matches and then removes them by using removeObjectAtIndex:.

So , use `removeObjectAtIndex` , or maybe `removeLastObject`.

Answer (score 3):

First you just need to get the index of one of the "farm" strings. If index is found, you can then remove the object at that index from your array.

```
NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObject:@"farm"];
if (index!=NSNotFound) {
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

`[array removeObjectAtIndex:<index of object to delete>];`